# Sublist in a List

Tags: python, list, sublist

Created a list `flowers`

```
>>> flowers = ['rose','bougainvillea','yucca','marigold','daylilly','lilly of the valley']
```

Then,

I had to assign to list `thorny` the sublist of list `flowers` consisting of the ﬁrst three objects in the list.

This is what I tried:

```
>>> thorny = []
>>> thorny = flowers[1-3]
>>> thorny
'daylilly'
>>> thorny = flowers[0-2]
>>> thorny
'daylilly'
>>> flowers[0,1,2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#76>", line 1, in <module>
    flowers[0,1,2]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
>>> thorny = [flowers[0] + ' ,' + flowers[1] + ' ,' + flowers[2]]
>>> thorny
['rose ,bougainvillea ,yucca']
```

How can I get just the first 3 objects of list flowers, while maintaining the look of a list inside a list?

Comment: Slice notation is done with a colon, not a minus sign.

Answer (score 18):

Slicing notation is `[:3]` not `[0-3]`:

```
In [1]: flowers = ['rose','bougainvillea','yucca','marigold','daylilly','lilly of the valley']

In [2]: thorny=flowers[:3]

In [3]: thorny
Out[3]: ['rose', 'bougainvillea', 'yucca']
```

Answer (score 8):

In Python:

```
thorny = flowers[1-3]
```

This equates to `flowers[-2]` because (1 - 3 == -2), and that means it looks from the end of the list, ie - the 2nd element from the end - eg daylilly...

To slice up to (but not including) the first 3 elements, you can use `thorny = flowers[:3]`, and if you wanted everything after those, then it's `flowers[3:]`.

Have a read up on Python slicing

Answer (score 5):

There can be 3 possible sublist types for any given list:

```
e1  e2  e3  e4  e5  e6  e7  e8  e9  e10     << list elements
|<--FirstFew-->|        |<--LastFew-->|
        |<--MiddleElements-->|
```

1. **FirstFew** are mostly presented by **+ve** indexes.

   ```
   First 5 elements - [:5]      //Start index left out as the range excludes nothing.
   First 5 elements, exclude First 2 elements - [2:5]
   ```
2. **LastFew** are mostly presented by **-ve** indexes.

   ```
   Last 5 elements - [-5:]       //End index left out as the range excludes nothing.
   Last 5 elements, exclude Last 2 elements - [-5:-2]
   ```
3. *MiddleElements* can be presented by both positive and negative index.

   ```
   Above examples [2:5] and [-5:-2] covers this category.
   ```

---

> just the first 3 objects of list flowers

```
[0 : 3]   //zero as there is nothing to exclude.
or
[:3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to do `flowers[0:3]` (or equivalently, `flowers[:3]`). If you did `flowers[0-3]` (for instance) it would be equivalent to `flowers[-3]` (i.e. the third to last item in `flowers`.).

Comment: At last, an answers that specifies how to set an offset for slicing!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
thorny = flowers[0:3]
```